# Passing values between 2 pages in Wp7 havig scrollviewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have 2 pages in my app each page has one scrollviewer having image as an item added dynamically form URL. The first contain the first image.When I scroll to the end of first page the second page have to appear with the next image, viceversa when I scroll to the end of the second page now the first page should contain the third image and next the second with the 4th image. how to do that. It is like an ebook application.

### This is in firstpage.xaml.cs

```
            Image img = new Image();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://d1mu9ule1cy7bp.cloudfront.net/2012/media/catalogues/47/pages/p_" + i + "/high.jpg");
            ImageSource img1 = new BitmapImage(uri);
            img.Source = img1;
            img.Height = 550;
            Scrollview.Content = img;

 private void Scrollview_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)       
       {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
       }
```

### This is in secondpage.xaml.cs

```
            int h = loop(j);

            Image img = new Image();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://d1mu9ule1cy7bp.cloudfront.net/2012/media/catalogues/47/pages/p_" + h + "/high.jpg");
            ImageSource img1 = new BitmapImage(uri);
            img.Source = img1;
            img.Height = 550;
            Scrollview.Content = img;

 private void Scrollview_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

       {

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

       }
```

Comment: You may want to reconsider your approach. It seems to me that unless you intend to have an arbritrary number of PageX.xaml files in your project this solution does not appear to be very flexible. 

You could consider scrolling to the end and simply loading new information on the same page and simply keep track of the page your on with some variable or indication on the main page.

Comment: i added 1 image in scrollview as an image element in first page. Can i add another image in that same scrollviewer by removed the first image in the same page using the swiping the image event instead of using the scrollend event

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a ListBox instead. It is a very powerful control.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to detect the end of scroll position on the first page and add the second image dynamically to that scollviewer itself. Something like infinite scrolling, similar to that of news feed in facebook app for wp7.